# lex/yacc and parser/scanner

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc, lex, lexical-analysis

lex and yacc are supposed to be used together.

Which ones is the scanner and which one is the parser?

Which one creates a scanner and which one creates a parser?

Comment: Seriously? You couldn't just, you know, check the manpage?

Comment: This stuff is kind of confusing so I need a live brain to verify me.

Comment: Wow, are you actually cheating on your final exam via StackOverflow? You've asked questions on lex and yacc before that were significantly more practical, so I'm forced to conclude that you just have no idea what you're doing and are diluting the value of a compsci degree for the rest of us.

Answer (score 5):

Lex (flex) is the lexical scanner. Yacc (bison) is the LALR parser generator.

Comment: So lex scans, and yacc creates a parser (it is not a parser itself.)

Comment: Correct. Lex generates tokens that are consumed by the parser generated from the yacc grammer.

Answer (score 3):

You will find that Wikipedia has excellent answers on all of these software tools and will explain them clearly and concisely. It's often the best place to start when you want a clear answer to a standard question.
Here is 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)

> In computer science, lex is a program
>   that generates lexical analyzers
>   ("scanners" or "lexers").[1] Lex is
>   commonly used with the yacc parser
>   generator.

And there is a lot more